# Read message protocol socket c

Tags: c, client

My code recovers all sent messages (ending with "\r\n") in function `read_message`. I would like to improve this code, make it more efficient? If it's possible, I am open to all reviews!

**Code**

```
static char     *read_message(char *data)
{
    static char     *buffer = NULL;
    char            *message = NULL;
    char            *ptr;
    size_t          size;

    if (buffer)
    {
        size = strlen(buffer) + strlen(data) + 1;
        if (!(buffer = realloc(buffer, size)))
            return (NULL);
        strcat(buffer, data);
    }
    else {
        if (!(buffer = strdup(data)))
            return (NULL);
    }
    if ((ptr = strstr(buffer, "\r\n")))
    {
        size = ((unsigned int)ptr - (unsigned int)buffer) + 1;
        if (!(message = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size)))
            return (NULL);
        strncpy(message, buffer, size);
        ptr += 2;
        if (!(ptr = strdup(ptr)))
            return (NULL);
        free(buffer);
        buffer = ptr;
    }
    return (message);
}

static t_message    *parse_message(char *buffer)
{
    int     id;

    id = atoi(buffer);
    printf("L'id du message est %d\n", id);
    return (NULL);
}

static void     handle_message(void)
{
    printf("OK\n");
}

void            listen_client(t_args *args)
{
    ssize_t     count;
    char        buffer[BUFF_SIZE + 1] = { 0 };
    char        *msg_str;
    t_message   *msg;

    while ((count = recv(args->client->s, buffer, BUFF_SIZE, 0)))
    {
        buffer[count] = '\0';
        if (!(msg_str = read_message(buffer)))
            continue ;
        if (!(msg = parse_message(msg_str)))    
            continue ;
        handle_message();
    }
    printf("Fin de connexion\n");
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `t_message`, as well as showing all relevant `#include`s.

Answer (score 2):

**Portability**

First this program could be made more portable. There are 2 portability issues here

If it was ported to a system that did not define end of line as "\r\n" this program might not work. This problem could be solved by including the proper header files or using

```
#define EndOfLine "\r\n"
```

and using

```
    ptr = strstr(buffer, EndOfLine)
```

The second portability issue is the use of `strdup()`. It is not implemented on all systems. This [Stackoverflow question discusses the use of strdup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c).

**Consistency in Coding Style**

There is one place in the code where the indentation is inconsistent:

```
    if (buffer)
    {
        size = strlen(buffer) + strlen(data) + 1;
        if (!(buffer = realloc(buffer, size)))
            return (NULL);
        strcat(buffer, data);
    }
    else {
        if (!(buffer = strdup(data)))
            return (NULL);
    }
```

The use of braces "{" and "}" should be consistent through the entire program.
Everywhere except in this code the brace starts on a new line.

It would be very nice if the headers were included for compilation and
testing. Without the headers or the calling functions it is difficult to
compile or test this code.

**Complexity**

It might be better if the function `read_message(char *data)` was separated
into multiple functions to reduce the complexity. All of the functions might
be more readable if there was some virtical spacing between blocks of code.

**Possible Bug**

The function `parse_message(char *buffer)` always returns NULL, in your
testing did the function `handle_message()` always get called?